# prove for function with property X(b) on E implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

I need help writing the following proof...

Given a positive number b and a set $E \subseteq  R$, let us say that a function $f : E \rightarrow R$ has property $X(b)$ on $E$ provided that for each pair $x, y \in E$ , $ |f(y) - f(x)| \ \leq  b|y-x| \ $

Statement of the problem: prove that if f has property X(b) on E then f is continuous on E.

What I have:

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary, and let $\delta = \epsilon / b$

Then we have $ |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever,  $b|y-x| \ < \delta $

Suppose

$$|y-x| \ < \delta  \rightarrow  |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$

$$ \rightarrow b|y-x|\ < \epsilon $$

$$\rightarrow  |f(y) - f(x)| \ \leq  b|y-x| \ < \epsilon $$

Thus,
$$ \rightarrow  |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$

Comment: You probably don't want to write $\epsilon / b$, in case $b=0$.  Simply say $b\delta < \epsilon$. Now if $|y-x| < \delta$, we have $|f(y)-f(x)| < b\delta < \epsilon$.

Comment: By the way, the property $X(b)$ is known as Lipschitz continuity, with Lipschitz constant $b$.

Comment: The question gave that b is a positive number so I didn't think it was necessary to worry about b = 0, but yes it is safer to say   <

Answer (score 1):

What you've written has everything that we need. I think you are just struggling to put it in the logical order.

Given: $b>0$ and for each pair $x, y \in E$, $\,\,\,|f(y) - f(x)| \ \leq  b|y-x|.$

Prove $f$ is (uniformly) continuous on E.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary, and let $\delta = \epsilon / b.$

Suppose  $|y-x| < \delta $.  Then $b|y-x| < \epsilon.$ Therefore $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$

Done. But what if $b=0$? Let $\delta = \epsilon / (b+1)$ from the beginning, or handle the obvious zero case separately.